# Match the element in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes: one dataframe `df1` with dates (they go by month) and codes

```
Dates       Codes
1/01/2016   AAA
1/02/2016   BBB
1/03/2016   CCC
1/04/2016   DDD
```

Another dataframe `df2` includes dates and several columns with codes

```
Dates      Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4 … Code100
1/01/2016   AAA  BBB   ABC   CCC     DCD
1/02/2016   AAA  BCB   DCA   CDA     ACA
1/03/2016   BBB  CCC   CBC   ACA     ABC
1/04/2016   CBC  BBB   AAA   DCD     CDC
```

What I need to do is to find out if at a particular date the company from `df1` is also included in `df2`.
I have tried to merge two dataframes using dates as a key and use match function. It merges fine, but now I need to locate the particular code (in Codes column) in any of Code1 - Code100 columns:

Merged dataframe `df3`:

```
Dates      Codes    Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4 … Code100
1/01/2016   AAA     AAA   BBB   ABC   CCC     DCD
1/02/2016   BBB     AAA   BCB   DCA   CDA     ACA
1/03/2016   CCC     BBB   CCC   CBC   ACA     ABC
1/04/2016   DDD     CBC   BBB   AAA   DCD     CDC

match(df3[1,2], df3[1,3:102])
```

returns False while it is clear that “AAA” is there in `df3[1, 3]`

What I need it to return is this:

```
Dates      Codes    Code1 Code2 Code3 Code4 … Code100 IsPresent
1/01/2016   AAA     AAA   BBB   ABC   CCC     DCD       1
1/02/2016   BBB     AAA   BCB   DCA   CDA     ACA       0
1/03/2016   CCC     BBB   CCC   CBC   ACA     ABC       1
1/04/2016   DDD     CBC   BBB   AAA   DCD     CDC       0
```

Comment: `df2[match(df1$Dates, df2$Dates), ]`

Comment: no, it does not work. For every `date`/`code` pair in `df1` I need it to find if the code is present in `df2` at the given date (= in a row that starts with that date).

Comment: Try, `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: i have no issues with merging - it merges fine as you see in df3. But my task is to locate the code in Codes for that particular date in the any of the corresponding Code1-Code100 columns.

Comment: Please update your post with the expected output.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `apply`. Checking if the values present in 2nd column of `df3` is included in any of the columns from 3rd to 102nd and converting the boolean value to numeric using `as.numeric`.

```
df3$IsPresent <- as.numeric(apply(df3, 1, function(x) x[2] %in% x[3:102]))

df3$IsPresent
# [1] 1 0 1 0
```